# Do we have adjectives that express that we feel like some needles pricking in our skin/hand/leg...?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Sometimes, I feel like there are some needles pricking in my heel/ arm / fingers etc but there is no needle pricking me.

I know what "**numb**" is, but that feeling of "**needle-pricking**" doesn't like "**numb**".

**Do we have adjectives that express that we feel like some needles pricking in our skin/hand/leg... in everyday conversation?**

Comment: Yes, it's popularly called 'having pins and needles in' your foot, hand or whatever.

Comment: If you are experiencing peripheral neuropathy you need to consult a medical professional.

Comment: The technical term (a noun) is [paresthesia](https://www.ninds.nih.gov/Disorders/All-Disorders/Paresthesia-Information-Page).

Comment: [***Formication**](https://www.healthline.com/health/formication#:~:text=What%20is%20formication%3F,as%20a%20type%20of%20paresthesia.) is the feeling of insects crawling across or underneath your skin.*

Comment: Another common way to describe this is "tingly"

Comment: Or "fell asleep"... and is "waking up." BTW, be careful not to misspell formication when using it. ;-)

Comment: @PeterKapteyn, is "**my finger's tip is stinging**" more or less the same as "**my finger's tip is tingling/tingly**"?

Comment: @Tom No, stinging implies a sharp pain. Tingly commonly refers to the 'pins and needles' sensation.